# How to export/import data on Android

Tags: android, share

I have an application that stores data in SQLite db. I've implemented export of this data to external file (in json format) with custom file extension. Also I have an activity that starts when user opens my file and saves it back to SQLite.
I don't want to backup my db, I'm exporting a part of data to be used by another users.

My next goal is to make sharing this data via Bluetooth (export it to Dropbox / send via email). I want it to look like described in this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html but I doubt that this tutorial is what I need.

I don't want users to export data to file and then send this file via Bluetooth, I want them to share data directly from my app.

- I looked at [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html). I'm confused with `insert`, `update` and other methods so I'm not sure this is the right choise.
- I looked at [Sending Binary Content tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content) but I don't know how to create intent properly and how to save my temporary file for sharing.

Please, describe the way to share this type of data or give me links to examples. Thanks!

P.S. sorry for my English